# The PaymentIntent requires a payment method — React, Django Rest

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I have a React app and a Django Rest API.

My goal is to get the PaymentRequestButtonElement working.

In my Stripe dashboard (test mode) I get the following logs:

```
200 OK
POST    
/v1/payment_intents
12:22:55 PM

200 OK
POST    
/v1/payment_methods
12:22:54 PM

200 OK
POST    
/v1/tokens
12:22:53 PM
```

But in the Payments tab, I get the following:

```
The PaymentIntent requires a payment method
```

Here is my React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { useShoppingCart } from 'use-shopping-cart';


import {
  PaymentRequestButtonElement,
  useStripe,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const PaymentRequest = () => {
  // const history = useNavigate();
  // const { totalPrice, cartDetails, cartCount } = useShoppingCart();
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = useState(null);
  const price = 350;

  const handleButtonClicked = (event) => {
    // if (!cartCount) {
    //   event.preventDefault();
    //   alert('Cart is empty!');
    //   return;
    // }
    paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', handlePaymentMethodReceived);
    paymentRequest.on('cancel', () => {
      paymentRequest.off('paymentmethod');
    });
    return;
  };

  const handlePaymentMethodReceived = async (event) => {
    // Send the cart details and payment details to our function.
    const paymentDetails = {
      payment_method: event.paymentMethod.id,
      shipping: {
        name: event.shippingAddress.recipient,
        phone: event.shippingAddress.phone,
        address: {
          line1: event.shippingAddress.addressLine[0],
          city: event.shippingAddress.city,
          postal_code: event.shippingAddress.postalCode,
          state: event.shippingAddress.region,
          country: event.shippingAddress.country,
        },
      },
    };
    const response = await fetch('https://my-api/create-payment-intent/', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        // cartDetails, 
        paymentDetails,
        amount: price,
        currency: 'usd',
        payment_method: 'card' 
        // automatic_payment_methods: true,
      }),
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    });
    if (response.error) {
      // Report to the browser that the payment failed.
      console.log(response.error);
      event.complete('fail');
    } else {
      // Report to the browser that the confirmation was successful, prompting
      // it to close the browser payment method collection interface.
      event.complete('success');
      // Let Stripe.js handle the rest of the payment flow, including 3D Secure if needed.
      const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
        response.paymentIntent.client_secret
      );
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      if (paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
        console.log('Payment succeeded!');
      } else {
        console.warn(
          `Unexpected status: ${paymentIntent.status} for ${paymentIntent}`
        );
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stripe && paymentRequest === null) {
      const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        total: {
          label: 'Demo total',
          // 
          amount: price,
          pending: true,
        },
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        requestShipping: true,
        shippingOptions: [
          {
            id: 'standard-global',
            label: 'Global shipping',
            detail: 'Handling and delivery fee',
            amount: 350,
          },
        ],
      });
      // Check the availability of the Payment Request API first.
      pr.canMakePayment().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          setPaymentRequest(pr);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [stripe, 
      paymentRequest, 
      // totalPrice
    ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (paymentRequest) {
      paymentRequest.update({
        total: {
          label: 'Demo total',
          amount: 350,
          pending: false,
        },
      });
    }
  }, [
      // totalPrice, 
      paymentRequest
    ]);

  if (paymentRequest) {
    return (
      <div className="payment-request-button">
        <PaymentRequestButtonElement
          options={{ paymentRequest }}
          onClick={handleButtonClicked}
        />
        --- OR ---
      </div>
    );
  }

  return '';
};

export default PaymentRequest;
```

and here is my Django REST View

```
class PaymentIntentView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        amount = request.data.get('amount')
        currency = request.data.get('currency')
        # automatic_payment_methods = request.data.get('automatic_payment_methods')

        try:
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=amount,
                currency=currency,
                # automatic_payment_methods={
                #     'enabled': True,
                # },
                # You can also add other options like capture_method, setup_future_usage, etc.
            )

            return Response({'client_secret': intent.client_secret, 'id': intent.id})
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)})
```

I've tried variations of passing automatic_payments as true and passing the payment_method as 'card', no joy

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options that you can do in order to fix the problem here.

**Option 1:** Pass the PM in the backend

When you call fetch on https://my-api/create-payment-intent/ you are passing the `paymentDetails` that you're not using in your `stripe.PaymentIntent.create` method. For this to work, you need to first deserialize your request to get access to this information since it's nested (e.g. this [guide](https://medium.com/@raaj.akshar/creating-reverse-related-objects-with-django-rest-framework-b1952ddff1c)). Then you need to pass `payment_method` to the `stripe.PaymentIntent.create` method. In this option you don't have to change anything in your frontend code.

**Option 2:** Pass the PM in the frontend

When you call `stripe.confirmCardPayment` you can pass in the payment_method as explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-data-payment_method). In this option you don't have to change anything in your backend code but you can remove the `paymentDetails` from the request to your backend.